# Grails & HibernateException: connnection proxy not usable after transaction completion

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I just ran into a problem I don't understand. Our grails (2.2.2) app is throwing the following exception just after the first user logged in. Once that one's done, no one has ever seen it again. Currently we're reproducing it with a Geb test.

```
Caused by HibernateSystemException: connnection proxy not usable after transaction completion; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: connnection proxy not usable after transaction completion
->>   24 | doCall    in gibbons5.recommender.ActivityRatingTagLib$_closure1
```

The line in the ActivityRatingTagLib (called by a gsp) is pretty simple:

```
if (!User.get(session.user.id).permissions.publishStream) {
```

If I remove the `User.get()` here and access the session.user right away, everything works fine but then it crashes in the next TagLib call in which the User is accessed via `User.get()`.

I was searching on the internet for solutions a lot now but nothing useful came up yet. As this exception seems to be rather uncommon, I guess we're doing something basically wrong, but what?

User.groovy:

```
class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {
    ...

    boolean isOnline = false
    Permissions permissions = new Permissions()

    static embedded = ['infoPopups', 'permissions', 'userSettings']

    void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        isOnline = true
    }

    void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        // we do not have a session any more
        withTransaction {
            def user = get(this.id)
            user.isOnline = false
            user.save()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Permissions.groovy:

```
class Permissions {
    boolean publishStream = false
}
```

Comment: I suppose you need to fetch `permissions` eagerly (`permissions lazy: false`) while getting the `user`. But before making my statement, if you can show the `User` domain in question that will be good.

Comment: The permissions are embedded and therefore should be loaded all the time. I added the two classes anyway!

Comment: Is ActivityRatingTagLib called inside a layout?

Comment: Plus if you can also show how you have implemented `valueBound` and `valueUnbound` for User as it implements `HttpSessionBindingListener`?

Comment: @dmahapatro: I added it as well.

Comment: @SérgioMichels: Yes. It's called in a gsp file:
    <gib:pinboardButtonAjax activity="${activity}" frame_id="${frame_id}" caller="${Caller.HOME}"/>

Comment: I've usually seen this kind of exceptions when domain objects are stores in session. I think it happens beacuse hibernate transaction has ended, and when you try to access a property (usually different from the id) it tries to retrieve the data but it can't because the hibernate session is no longer valid. To avoid this kind of problems, I suggest not storing in session domain objects, just store for example the user id and retrieve it when needed.

Comment: @Eylen Shouldn't it be a LazyInitializationException in the case you described?

Comment: it's strange, but I have also seen this exception in those cases...

Comment: @Eylen So I tried that and removed all persisted objects from the session. We're now only saving the id and loading the entity again upon request. Didn't help :(

Comment: @SérgioMichels: Yes it is called inside a layout. Could that be a problem? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same exception thrown from a migration script, solved it in the following way (Grails 2.2.0):

```
User.withNewSession {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSessionInView, responsible for making the hibernate session available when working with GSP's and TagLib's isn't available in your layouts.

My solution when I hit this problem was to wrap the database calls with the closure `withTransaction`:

```
def myTag = { attrs, body ->
  User.withTransaction {
    //GORM methods...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For information: i use WAS server and i think there is a connectivity between hibernate and was connection pool. so, i decided not to close my conn and checked whether hibernate uses the connection on WAS or open a new one. I saw that the problem'd gone and there was only one connection as idle at the end. So my advice ( if you use WAS server and a singleton connection architect) you should try not to close the last used connection before reaching this code